# Problem with sockets on Black Hat Python code book

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've trying to follow this book's code, but is written in python 2. At first, I tried to run the book's code:

```
import socket

target_host = "www.google.com"
target_port = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect((target_host,target_port))

msg = "Hi!"

"""MSG = msg.encode()"""
client.send(msg)

response = client.recv(4096)

print(response)
```

Then it run into this error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'. Which I corrected with some encoding like this:

```
import socket

target_host = "www.google.com"
target_port = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect((target_host,target_port))

msg = "Hi!"
MSG = msg.encode()
client.send(MSG)

response = client.recv(4096)

print(response)
```

But now, the code doesn't print anything. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The book's code is send "GET / HTTP/1.1\Host: google.com\r\n\r\n".
This code means send a get request to google, so it can get response for request you sent .
Your msg is not a HTTP's request, so google will not send response for you msg.